# OpenShift - behaviour of gears

Tags: java, heroku, openshift

I wanted to use OpenShift for a small project at university. I do not need data persistence, I just have a Java EE application running.

I now from Heroku, that idling dynos are destroyed and recovered when needed again. Because the sessions of the user using my service might endure some time (with idle in between) I am curious if OpenShift also destroys the gears in idle and if so, after how much time of being in idle state?

Somebody got some experience or information on this? I couldn't find what I was looking for in the official documentation...

BR
Florian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From openshift page.

> **Application idling**
>   Your application will idle if it does not receive
>   an http request from outside of your gear **in 24 hours**. Your
>   application will automatically start up again when it receives its
>   first http request thereafter. **Application idling does not occur at**
>   **the Bronze and Silver plan**.

Comment: Argh... Than I overlooked that :)
Do you know what they mean by "idling"? I guessed it is already idling when there is no request for 24 hours. Do they kill the gear?

Comment: From another Openshift documentation :
host's resources efficiently by idling unused application gears, **which means that you shut down inactive gears.**

Comment: I already got that credit :)
And I think once the development of the application is done I will move it over there. But for testing purposes during development deployment (for colleges testing) at OpenShift is much faster and easier I think.

Comment: Just upgrade to Bronze and your application won't idle (and it's still free).

Comment: OpenShift also has a program for edu's and non-profits https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-for-non-profits-open-source-and-educational-institutions/